# How to create new *.msg file with my data and attachments using existing *.msg as template in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, outlook

Does anybody know of any JavaScript libraries that could open existing *.msg  Outlook file created for example as template, and could use code to put data like to, subject, any {} other data and save it to disk as new.msg file?

Explain detailed:
 I have customer data, like email, name, some other data and attachment pdf what i need to send to my customer.
Olso I have created by Outlook software file customer.msg and would like to use it as template.

**I need use Nodejs code to open *.msg file and put my customer data like "TO, SUBJECT, any data in the text places that are prepared in template {someData} and attachment to this email and save it for future sending.**

What I have tryed:

npm eml-format - for only creating emails what also support outlook, but only eml extension. It can not use *.msg files as templates.

npm shild-process - for opening other files like *.msg, *.eml

nodemailer - but this only for sendind emails and did not meet my requiments.

I spend all day for finding solution and unsuccessfully. Help please.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a bit late, but still it might help someone.

I had similar requirements, and I found this proprietary library [msg js](https://www.independentsoft.de/msgjs/index.html).
It fulfils all your requirements:

- [Read .msg files](https://www.independentsoft.de/msgjs/tutorial/createmessage.html)
- [Create .msg files](https://www.independentsoft.de/msgjs/tutorial/readmessage.html)

Comment: Both links provided lead to a very shady library with an unusual license and obfuscated code - be very careful of using it